# remove password from my verizon S4 mini

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

I forgot my password for my phone and i eventually did a factory reset which i was told would remove all my data including the password. Well that was not the case. They password is still on the phone.  and verizon was no help either.Please help me. I'm not in the position to purchase a new phone. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURED IT OUT!! I went back into factory reset mode because it had other options on the list besides factory reset, I noticed that it had something about cache and then i remembered that when you want to do a clean install of anything and want to start from scratch, you have to make sure that you clear the cache too. So that's what i did first and then i did another factory reset which worked this time. No more issues with the forgotten password!!! – elaine.c